# Removing/deleting the alternate numbers from a list in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a problem statement i.e In the case of 10 persons with chairs arranged in a circle. There is a pattern of skipping one person and asking the next to leave(starting from the first person in the list). Say, 10 persons in in circle numbered 1 to 10. Persons were asked to leave in this order `1,3,5,7,9,2,6,10` and `8`. So, person `4` is the winner.

What would be the approach to get the expected result. I tried it using array of 10 elements and programming like this,

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

`arr = arr.each_slice(2).map(&:second)`

and again doing the same to the returned result till I get one element, but I am not getting the expected result. eg;

```
arr.each_slice(2).map(&:second)
=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10].each_slice(2).map(&:second)
=> [4, 8, nil]
[4, 8, nil].each_slice(2).map(&:second)
=>[8, nil]
```

In this case the output is but I am expecting 4. Is there some simpler way to do this and get the desired output?

Comment: Undefined method `second`.

Comment: `second` is a method in `ActiveSupport`. Not basic ruby.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solution would only work if `arr.size` is a power of 2. For example, in your second step, you get:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10].each_slice(2).to_a #=> [[2, 4], [6, 8], [10]]
```

This is where the `nil` comes from: Because `[10].second == nil`.

Moreover, the logic is flawed: On the next iteration of the loop, it's the *second* person who needs to leave, not the first.

What you need to do is keep track of "should the next person leave?" as a separate concern to the array index.

Here's a possible solution:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
should_delete = [true, false].cycle
while(arr.size > 1)
  arr.delete_if { should_delete.next }
end

p arr #=> [4]
```

`[true, false].cycle` creates an infinite enumerator, of `[true, false, true, false, true, .....]`. So as we loop over and over the array, we keep track of whether the next person must leave by this variable.

---

Side note: This is a famous puzzle, known as the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem). I recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCsD3ZGzMgE) for a good explanation. You can actually determine the "winner" via a simple formula, rather than looping over the array like that!

Comment: Mindblowing! What a brilliant use of enumerators!

Comment: @tom-lord  Thanks for sharing the extra details like the the video and the wiki. It was helpful.

Comment: Nice one, Tom !

Answer (score 6):

As the chairs are arranged in a circle, you can just do something like:

- Take the first chair in the list and throw it out
- Rotate the circle (move the first chair to the end of list, essentially skipping it)
- Repeat until there's only one seat left

In code:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

until arr.size == 1
  arr.delete_at(0)
  arr.rotate!
end
```

Comment: Think you might be able to use `shift` instead of `delete_at(0)`.

Comment: @SagarPandya yes, I had it in there but thought `delete_at(0)` is more syntactically correct

Comment: Nice answer, Kimmo, but please don't be so rough with the chairs.

Answer (score 1):

```
def last_person_standing(arr)
  (arr.size-1).times.reduce(arr) { |a,_| a << a.shift(2).last }.first
end
```

A few points follow.

- If the array contains `n` elements there are `n-1` steps, with one element of the array being removed at each step;
- by using [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) there is no need to add a line at the end to return desired value;
- to avoid mutating `arr` replace `reduce`'s argument (`arr`) with `arr.dup`;
- `a << a.shift(2).last` removes the first two elements of the array `a` and appends the second of those to the end of `a`;
- I've tacked `.first` onto the end of the operative line to return the remaining element rather than an array containing that single element, as it seems more useful; and
- code should be added to deal with the cases where `arr.size < 2`.

Let's try it.

```
last_person_standing %w| Agnes Billy-Bob Trixy Bubba Wanda |
   #=> "Billy-Bob"
```

More examples follow.

```
(2..10).each do |n|
   a = [*1..n]
   puts "#{ a }: #{ last_person_standing(a) }"
end
```

prints

```
[1, 2]: 2
[1, 2, 3]: 2
[1, 2, 3, 4]: 4
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]: 2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]: 4
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]: 6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]: 8
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]: 2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]: 4
```

Here's another way.

```
def last_person_standing(arr)
  while arr.size > 1
    odd = arr.size.odd?
    arr.pop if odd
    arr.delete_if.with_index { |_,i| i.even? }
    arr.unshift(nil) if odd
  end
  arr.first
end
```

If, after each round of deletions from `arr`, if `arr.size` is odd, pop off the last element of `arr`, remove elements from `arr` with even indices and then `unshift` any placeholder-object (I chose `nil`) at the beginning of `arr` (to be removed in the next cycle); if `arr.size` is even simply remove elements from `arr` with even indices.